# How to find multiple row pairings (with potential rows between the members of a pairing)

Tags: python, pandas

sorry I realize the question title is somewhat vague, I wasn't sure how to phrase the question.  Hopefully this example will make what I'm trying to do clear.

I have a dataframe like so:

```
    Time    Event
0    .1      start
1    .2      end
2    .3      start
3    .4      foo
4    .5      bar
5    .6      end
```

I am trying to get the indices of the corresponding start and end rows (so in this example, the pairs (0,1) and (2,5)).

I'm not entirely sure how to write a vectorized version of this code.  I could do it fairly easily in a loop, but am trying to avoid it.

Assumptions that can be made:

-Every start has an associated end

-Starts and ends can have other events between them

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I realized my question missed one key case.  I can have an event that starts within another event.  So a dataframe like:

```
    Time    Event
0    .1      start
1    .2      start
2    .3      end
3    .4      foo
4    .5      bar
5    .6      end
```

where the results should be (0,2), (1,5)

I realize this completely changes the nature of the question.  Sorry for not mentioning it earlier.  Would a stack be the easiest way to handle this?

Comment: Open a new question with your completely new requirements. Don't edit it into this one.

Comment: The original question stated starts and ends can have other events between them, I just failed to elaborate on a specific case that complicates things.  I don't believe it's actually a new question.

Comment: @Vaishali For OP's new input, you should be getting `(0,5), (1,2)`, not `[(0, 2), (1, 5)]`. So for the nested bit your answer won't work.

Comment: @OP I think you should ask a new question if you want a working solution for your nested case, because it needs a more involved answer.

Comment: I actually wrote it incorrectly, her solution works.  I've accepted it. I need to get some sleep.

Comment: You should be clear on what you want. because your expected output is different from the actual output that you seem to think is correct. You might want to change that or you'd confuse future readers.

Comment: I already have.

Comment: I did not follow up the question, I answered .. ....:(

Comment: Sorry, I gave you an upvote, but Vaishali's answer already worked in the odd case where another event is started within the first event's window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the indices in two different lists and join lists to create the tuple

```
start = df[(df['Event'] == 'start')].index
end = df[(df['Event'] == 'end')].index
[(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in zip(start, end) if i1 < i2]
```

You get

```
[(0, 1), (2, 5)]
```

It will handle any un-even pair of start-end. With your updated dataframe,

```
    Time    Event
0    .1      start
1    .2      start
2    .3      end
3    .4      foo
4    .5      bar
5    .6      end
```

this solution gives

```
[(0, 2), (1, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one ?

```
df['Group']=df.Event.eq('start').cumsum()
df.groupby('Group').agg(['idxmin','idxmax'])
Out[797]: 
        Time       
      idxmin idxmax
Group              
1          0      1
2          2      5
```

Or you can have a list output

```
df.groupby('Group').agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).values.tolist()
Out[800]: [[0, 1], [2, 5]]
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, this is a great answer, but I missed one key case that throws it off.  Do you have any idea how to handle the nesting?